# Is it possible to pass data from SKScene to ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, skscene, arkit

I am working on an SpriteKit ARKit project that I am trying to pass data from SKScene to a new instantiate ViewController.

My goal is, once the user tap on a node with identifier, a new viewController will instantiate and navigate to the VC with performSeque.

Currently I am able to performSeque and navigate to the new instantiated VC. However, even I set the vc.data = result (A variable that has been verified with value) and print it out to check. However, when the new view is up, the vc.data is not being set and no data being pass from the SKScene to ViewController.

I have attached my code snippet for reference.

I am new to SKScene and swift, and will need your guidance. Much appreciated.

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }

    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    let hit = nodes(at: location)


    if let node = hit.first { if node.name == "targetLabel" {

            guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TargetViewController") as? TargetViewController else {
                print("Could not instantiate view controller with identifier of type TargetViewController")
                return
            }

            vc.data = result

            //Even print to check
            print("Got result in vc.data?: \(vc.data)")


           self.viewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTargetViewController", sender: vc)

        }
```

...